# Android sofware LBE Security like possibly without root

Tags: android, security

I'm searching for a software like LBE Security with this features:

- permission control + fake data feed for the apps/services
- setup of the default operation: eg: block/fake data to all the requests (all solutions I found generally permit all as default making you have to block the apps manually the first time)
- **possibly no root requirements**
- **android 5.1.x lollipop**
- open source / active community

Can you suggest me something? I would like start using my phone but having some control over it. I wish to block also some google services from having too much data :)

PS: Suggested around there's Xprivacy but it requires root privileges. I would like to have my device with any modifications including root.

PPS: For the sake of comparison I could go also for a solution with root but **android 5.1.x compatible and for sure stable and open source**.

Comment: Without root that's close to impossible, or at least restricted to very few things. To do what you want, that app needed to interfere with the Android system. To do that, it would need the required power. I don't know about any such app not requiring root to achieve this; maybe one "slipped through" (I'd like to hear from it then), but it's rather unlikely.

Comment: @Izzy Hmm, ok so even if my best choice go for a non rooted one I edited my original question allowing a root solution but keeping the other requirements, if I remember Xprivacy is not Lollipop 5.1.1 compatible.

Comment: You're welcome to take a look at my list of [Permission Manager](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_380). I was using LBE for quite a while, and currently I'm using Xprivacy – but I'm not at 5.1.1, so I cannot place a "convincing answer".

Comment: @Izzy i see, then considering I could decide to move (but this is only for my old phone out of warranty sadly, not related to he main question so) to a Cyanogenmod. How about their permission manager? It works with fake data too? Is a viable way to revamp an old phone and also get rid of privacy leaks from the various installed apps? Did you had a chance to try it?

Comment: A chance I would have (running CM on both of my phones), but I didn't. Found it too limited, though I cannot remember exactly what was missing. And yes, according to [a PocketNow article](http://pocketnow.com/android/cyanogenmod-adds-advanced-app-permission-control), it even does "spoofing" for selected data, returning false data rather than deny access. For details, a web search on "cyanogenmod privacy guard" should be helpful.